# sum of array column

Tags: php, arrays, sum

Anyone here can help me solve this? I just want to get the total or sum of certain  column, please refer to the image below. Been trying to sort this for 2days but cant 
get no luck, Hope anyone can help me with this. I appreciate it so much, and thanks in 
advance.

Here is a sample image http://www.freeimagehosting.net/pig81

```
<?php $sql = "SELECT name, doc_date, descs, debit, credit FROM statement WHERE  
member_id = $member_id ORDER BY doc_date";

$query = mysql_query($sql);
$combinedResults = array();

while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
$combinedResults[$result[`name`]][] = array(`name` => $result[`name`], `doc_date` =>   
$result[`doc_date`], `descs` => $result[`descs`],`debit` => $result[`debit`], `credit` 
=> $result[`credit`]);}

foreach(array_keys($combinedResults) as $groupKey) { ?>
<table>
  <tr><?php  foreach($combinedResults[$groupKey] as $item) {?>
    <td>Date</td>
    <td>Description</td>
    <td>Debit</td>
    <td>Credit</td>
    <td>Balance</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><?php  echo $groupKey; ?></td>
<td width="105">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="105">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="105">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr><?php  foreach($combinedResults[$groupKey] as $item) {?>
<td><?php echo $item[`doc_date`];?></td>
<td><?php echo $item[`descs`];?></td>
<td><?php echo $item[`debit`];?></td>
<td><?php echo $item[`credit`]; ?></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>sum of debit goes here</td>
</tr>
<?php }} ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've refactored the code based on what I see in it, and added a balance calculator, but I haven't actually tested it.

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT name, doc_date, descs, debit, credit
        FROM statement
        WHERE  member_id = $member_id
        ORDER BY doc_date";

$query = mysql_query($sql);
$combinedResults = array();

// Slurp SQL results into array
while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
  $combinedResults[$result['name']][] = array(
    'name' => $result['name'],
    'doc_date' => $result['doc_date'],
    'descs' => $result['descs'],'debit' => $result['debit'],
    'credit' => $result['credit']
  );
}

// Define a format for all table lines (add CSS as required)
$fmt = "<tr>\n  <td>%s</td>\n  <td>%s</td>\n  <td>%s</td>\n  <td>%s</td>\n  <td>%s</td>\n</tr>";

print "<style type='text/css'>TD{width:105px;}</style>\n";

print "<table>\n";

// Walk through array...
foreach ($combinedResults[$groupKey] as $item) {
  // Start a section...
  printf($fmt, "Date", "Description", "Debit", "Credit", "Balance");
  printf($fmt, $groupKey, "", "", "", "");
  $balance = 0; // Initialize the balance for this section...
  foreach ($combinedResults[$groupKey] as $item) {
    printf($fmt, $item['doc_date'], $item['descs'], $item['debit'], $item['credit'], "");
    $balance += $item['debit'];
  }
  printf($fmt, "", "", "", "", $balance); // Print the balance.
}

print "</table>\n";
```

I'm interested to know if it works.  :)

Note that I didn't make allowances for your "colspan"; I suspect that you should settle on your logic before you try to build it into an actual layout.

Comment: hi ghoti, thanks for the reply. i think its working, but it just need a little adjustment because it loops or displays multiple results depending on the number of items. here is the the sample output http://www.freeimagehosting.net/xx7bc

Comment: hi ghoti, its me again. ITS WORKING NOW, thanks so much for your time and help.. appreciate so much.

Answer (score 2):

You can change your SQL Statement with something like

```
SELECT name, doc_date, descs, debit, credit, SUM(debit) AS sum FROM statement WHERE member_id = $member_id ORDER BY doc_date
```

You then print it with

```
<?php echo $item['sum']; ?>
```

You might also want to have a look either at [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) that replace `mysql_` functions.

Comment: hi J-P, the query results returns only 1 item. any idea?